# Distinct() How to find unique elements in list of objects

Tags: c#, linq, distinct

There is a very simple class:

```
public class LinkInformation
{
    public LinkInformation(string link, string text, string group)
    {
        this.Link = link;
        this.Text = text;
        this.Group = group;
    }

    public string Link { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Group { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Link.PadRight(70) + Text.PadRight(40) + Group;
    }
}
```

And I create a list of objects of this class, containing multiple duplicates.

So, I tried using `Distinct()` to get a list of unique values.

But it does not work, so I implemented

```
IComparable<LinkInformation>

    int IComparable<LinkInformation>.CompareTo(LinkInformation other)
    {
        return this.ToString().CompareTo(other.ToString());
    }
```

and then...

```
IEqualityComparer<LinkInformation>

    public bool Equals(LinkInformation x, LinkInformation y)
    {
        return x.ToString().CompareTo(y.ToString()) == 0;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(LinkInformation obj)
    {
        int hash = 17;
        // Suitable nullity checks etc, of course :)
        hash = hash * 23 + obj.Link.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 23 + obj.Text.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 23 + obj.Group.GetHashCode();
        return hash;
    }
```

The code using the `Distinct` is:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] filePath = {   @"C:\temp\html\1.html",
                                @"C:\temp\html\2.html",
                                @"C:\temp\html\3.html",
                                @"C:\temp\html\4.html",
                                @"C:\temp\html\5.html"};

        int index = 0;

        foreach (var path in filePath)
        {
            var parser = new HtmlParser();

            var list = parser.Parse(path);

            var unique = list.Distinct();

            foreach (var elem in unique)
            {
                var full = new FileInfo(path).Name;
                var file = full.Substring(0, full.Length - 5);
                Console.WriteLine((++index).ToString().PadRight(5) + file.PadRight(20) + elem);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

What has to be done to get `Distinct()` working?

Comment: Show your `.Distinct()` query please

Comment: Can you show the Equal and GetHashCode implementation in the first?

Comment: Did you pass your `IEqualityComparer` to the call to `Distinct`?

Comment: I added the code where I call Distinct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to actually pass the `IEqualityComparer` that you've created to `Disctinct` when you call it.  It has two overloads, one accepting no parameters and one accepting an `IEqualityComparer`.  If you don't provide a comparer the default is used, and the default comparer doesn't compare the objects as you want them to be compared.

Comment: Yes, thats it! Thank you so much!

Comment: @MareInfinitus If the class should be able to compare itself for equality, and not require a separate comparer, then have it implement `IEquatable` or override `object.Equals` while also overriding `object.GetHashCode`.  That will affect the behavior of the default equality comparer.

Comment: I have done that, as can be seen above... but it really did not work. Maybe a problem with the implementation, but I did not see it. And used the same in the comparer, where it actually worked.

Comment: @MareInfinitus You created a separate object to be a custom comparer that provides equals/gethashcode implementations by implementing the `IEqualityComparer` interface.  You did not override the implementations of `object` in the type itself.

Comment: With the implementation that I used beforehand. But I had some error in the implementation I believe. Now I am glad it works. "It just works" is what I need here, it's just a small private project.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return distinct elements from sequences of objects of some custom data type, you have to implement the IEquatable generic interface in the class.

here is a sample implementation:

```
public class Product : IEquatable<Product>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Code { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Product other)
    {

        //Check whether the compared object is null.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(other, null)) return false;

        //Check whether the compared object references the same data.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;

        //Check whether the products' properties are equal.
        return Code.Equals(other.Code) && Name.Equals(other.Name);
    }

    // If Equals() returns true for a pair of objects 
    // then GetHashCode() must return the same value for these objects.

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {

        //Get hash code for the Name field if it is not null.
        int hashProductName = Name == null ? 0 : Name.GetHashCode();

        //Get hash code for the Code field.
        int hashProductCode = Code.GetHashCode();

        //Calculate the hash code for the product.
        return hashProductName ^ hashProductCode;
    }
}
```

And this is how you do the actual distinct:

```
Product[] products = { new Product { Name = "apple", Code = 9 }, 
                       new Product { Name = "orange", Code = 4 }, 
                       new Product { Name = "apple", Code = 9 }, 
                       new Product { Name = "lemon", Code = 12 } };

//Exclude duplicates.

IEnumerable<Product> noduplicates =
    products.Distinct();
```

Comment: One does *not* need to have the objects implement `IEquatable`.  Creating an `IEqualityComparer` is also fine, as is overriding `Equals` and `GetHashCode` without `IEquatable`.  The OP already has an` IEqualityComparer`, so going that route is perfectly fine.

Comment: Despite, it does not work. But I really would enjoy implementing the class so that it works with Distinct out of the box, without the need to implement more classes.

Comment: Okay, it should work if implemented correctly. +1 after all. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy with defining the "distinctness" by a single property, you can do

```
list
    .GroupBy(x => x.Text)
    .Select(x => x.First())
```

to get a list of "unique" items.

No need to mess around with `IEqualityComparer` et al.

Comment: He *doesn't* have a single property as the identity of the object though.  He's using three.

Comment: So, did you get a look at the actual data? ;-)

Comment: One of them, the `Link` would be unique. So your way is actually working, despite not using Distinct... but this is not the problem here. Thank you!

Comment: Correct. +1 to @servy for answering the real question. :-)

Comment: Who would downvote giving another idea solving the problem that the code has? strange... @downvoter: Please leave a comment, I am interested in it.

Comment: Thanks @MareInfinitus for raising the question. Of course, I'd also be interested in the rationale behind the downvote, but I suspect we will never know...

Answer (score 1):

Without using Distinct nor the comparer, how about:

```
list.GroupBy(x => x.ToString()).Select(x => x.First())
```

I know this solution is not the answer for the exact question, but I think is valid to be open for other solutions.

Comment: what a nice idea! I never thought of that!

Comment: There's absolutely no point in doing this, since you'd get the same behavior by `list.GroupBy(x => x.ToString()).Select(x => x.First());`. No need to recreate the object from the key/`ToString()`, that is.

Comment: You are right Christoffer, I'll modify my post thanks

Comment: ...and now your answer is pretty much the same as my answer. ;-)

Comment: Pretty much, I raised it now ;)